# PHP script link the *last* files in a folder

Tags: php

The way I have organized the reports in a particular folder on my site is fairly straight forward. First they all have the date, in big endian mode. This means the most recent report should be at the bottom.

So, the reports are named like this

```
20110102China01
20110105China01
```

Does anybody know a trick to have PHP pick out the very first or last thing in the folder?

Comment: Also folder ordering and alphabetical ordering are completely different.

Comment: Mahmoud, thanks for your comment but it is not correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Big_endian_forms.2C_starting_with_the_year

Answer (score 2):

You can make a call to shell_exec to execute a shell command. If you're doing this in a Linux environment, your command can look like one of the following.

Get the first file alphabetically in the directory:

```
$result = shell_exec("ls | head -n 1");
```

Get the last file alphabetically in the directory:

```
$result = shell_exec("ls | tail -n 1");
```

Comment: You're correct, ls does return results sorted alphabetically (case-sensitive) by default. I've seen a variant of this where ls was aliased to `ls | sort -fd` in order to sort case-insensitive, which is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `glob()` to grab them all and then getting the last thing in the array returned.

```
$contents = glob('path/to/directory');
$file = $contents[count($contents) - 1];
echo $file;
```

To get the first one do this.

```
$contents = glob('path/to/directory');
$file = $contents[0];
echo $file;
```